# Launching MSYS2 MinGW 64 is very slow when the computer is offline

Tags: mingw-w64

When the computer is not connected to the Internet, launching the MinGW 64 (MSYS2) console requires more than one minute (and also compiling with gcc becomes very slow).
My computer (windows 7 pro) is not joined to any Active Directory.
When the computer is connected to the Internet, everything is fine.

What is the reason? Is There a way to fix it?

Comment: Is your own hostname (as seen by your MinGW environment) resolvable i.e. can you ping your own hostname and you see it resolved to 127.0.0.1?  Sounds like that could be related.

Comment: @istepaniuk yes I can ping my own hostname. I also tried to disable the antivirus, no luck.

Comment: @istepaniuk I found I had an odd entry in the hosts file (I added it a long time ago while making other tests), you point me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found that the file C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts had an odd entry before the standard `127.0.0.1 localhost` entry:

```
127.0.0.1 mytest
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Deleting the first (or placing the `127.0.0.1 localhost` first) solved the problem.